# How can i convert this table?

Tags: r

I have a large table, which is structured as follows:

```
 Date        Abbreviation  Value
1 2019-01-01         NR_1     1
2 2020-01-01         NR_1     2
3 2019-01-01         NR_2     3
4 2020-01-01         NR_2     4
5 2019-01-01        NR_12     5
6 2020-01-01        NR_12     6
```

How can i reconstruct this table to this:

```
  Date        NR_1  NR_2  NR_12
1 2019-01-01    1    3     5
2 2020-01-01    2    4     6
```

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
library('data.table')
dcast(setDT(df), formula = Date ~ Abbreviation)

#          Date NR_1 NR_12 NR_2
# 1: 2019-01-01    1     5    3
# 2: 2020-01-01    2     6    4
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 'Date        Abbreviation  Value
1 2019-01-01         NR_1     1
      2 2020-01-01         NR_1     2
      3 2019-01-01         NR_2     3
      4 2020-01-01         NR_2     4
      5 2019-01-01        NR_12     5
      6 2020-01-01        NR_12     6', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```